# How to identify from PowerShell if an PowerPoint or LibreOffice presentation is running?

Tags: windows, powershell, skype, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I have a PowerShell script that runs via a periodic scheduled task and throws up a notification on the screen.  How can I identify if the computer is currently giving a presentation to prevent that or delay it until the presentation is over?

I don't think this is identifying the official "Presentation Mode" because that is (theoretically) only for laptops.

Is there some kind of identifiable "do-not-disturb" state when PowerPoint (or LibreOffice Impress) or Acrobat or Skype or something else in a full-screen mode for a presentation?

**Edit:**  If there is no system-wide "do-not-disturb", is there a way to identify applications in full-screen mode?  I.E. not just a maximized window, but the view with no window frame, no start bar, etc.?  Maybe called "kiosk-mode"?  I'm not opposed to checking if any of a set of common presentation-like applications are in a mode like that.

Comment: Look for the app service process, before taking any action. You can only know if it is running, not what operational state it is in.

Comment: If you can make use of the Windows 10 Notifications, then the system and user can manage if they are being shown.

Answer (score 1):

> > How can I identify if the computer is currently giving a presentation to prevent that or delay it until the presentation is over?

I'm not sure how you'd do it in PowerShell but from any COM or VBA process with a reference to the PowerPoint application, this will tell you whether there are slide shows running:

```
Application.SlideShowWindows.Count
```

Any value > 0 means there's a slide show active.

> > I don't think this is identifying the official "Presentation Mode" because that is (theoretically) only for laptops

If you mean Presenter View, then no, it's available on desktops as well. In either case, it's only useful if there's a second monitor or projector attached.

> > Is there some kind of identifiable "do-not-disturb" state when PowerPoint (or LibreOffice Impress) or Acrobat or Skype or something else in a full-screen mode for a presentation

No, but not for lack of begging MS for it. Some versions of Windows have a presenter mode that quells *some* (but not all, I think) chatter from other software during presentations.